# How do I get rid of cyclic references in this design?

Tags: design, c++, multithreading, smart-pointer

I have 3 classes: **Meeting**, **Project** and **Agenda**.

- A **Project** contains all sort of information + a list of meetings.
- The **Agenda** contains a list of upcoming Meetings.
- A **Meeting** contains some data + a list of Projects that were discussed there.

The Agenda checks for upcoming meetings. When it finds one, it calls its *Meeting::alarm()* method, which in turn displays data it gets from the list of projects this meeting refers to.

**Meetings** can be referenced in a project without being scheduled in the **Agenda**, but it doesn't really make sense to have a reference to a meeting in the agenda if it is not contained in a project.

[image: Dependency between the classes]

Because the **Agenda** can be parsed in a thread while the main thread deletes a **project**, I made both Agenda and Project use shared pointers on Meetings, so that the parsing thread doesn't find a dangling pointer.

In the destructor of **Project**, I ask **Agenda** to check the meetings related to this project to clean up those who don't have any other related project.

Here is my problem:
*What kind of data structure should the Meeting::parentProjects member be?*
If a Meeting gets called by the Agenda while its Project is being deleted, and parentProjects is a simple raw pointers container, I might have a dangling here. But I can't use a shared_ptr to Project either, since that would make a cyclic dependency... I feel like it is unnecessarily complicated.

*How could I refactor this?* Note: I **have to** keep the 2 threads though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are asking this question seems to imply that you expect the answer has to be in data structure.  I'm not sure that it is.

The key problem is that you are wanting to modify and access the data at the same time, and have realised that attempting to access partially modified data is not good.

There are several strategies that you can do with this.

1. In an environment where all actions on data are quick, and there is a
   low volume of changes you could use a Mutex (or if
   you want, light weight semaphores) and force the second action to block
   until the first action had completed.
2. If these actions can take a noticeable time to occur. (e.g. 1/2 a second or
   more) then I would be tempted to create an action queue, and to have a your 
   current threads place tasks on the queue, and have a third thread that
   performed these actions in sequence, calling a callback on the task to 
   notify the original thread it was completed.

In simple terms, the major problem you have is the concurrent data access, rather than the data structure, so you need to solve it by managing the access, rather than by a pure data structure approach.

Answer (score 0):

Although I share Ptolemy's concerns about the design, there is also a straightforward answer.

`Meeting::parentProjects` should be a weak_ptr. This does require that the Project lifetime is controlled by shared_ptr in the first place.

> If a Meeting gets called by the Agenda while its Project is being deleted ...

let's break this down. Either:

1. Meeting is called, while parent Project is still alive (shared_ptr has nonzero refcount)

   - calling `weak_ptr::lock` yields a shared_ptr which keeps the parent Project alive for the duration of this call
   - when the current call ends the shared_ptr implementing the temporary lock goes out of scope

   or
2. Meeting is called after parent Project has been destroyed (shared_ptr has zero refcount)

   - calling `weak_ptr::lock` yields an empty shared_ptr: you can test for this and decide how to handle it

So, the Meeting will never keep its Project alive *except while it's using it*, and the Project *cannot* be deleted while the Meeting is using it.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature of weak_ptr. I will use it as a last resort but for now I'm trying to reorganize things as @Ptolemy suggests.

Comment: I always thought of cycle-breaking as the primary motivation for weak_ptr, tbh.